# Haskell Sections in Agda

Tags: haskell, agda

In Haskell we can section a binary operation `⊕` to obtain two functions
`(x ⊕)` and `(⊕ y)`. As far as I know, we can mimic the first section by writing `_⊕_ x` but can we do so cleanly for the second section?

**Example**
Here I define an already sectioned version of Agda library's `Function._$_` to perform the second section as mentioned above.
However, it does not work in my desired case below and I do not know why.
Any insight is welcome!

```
$ : ∀ {a b} {A : Set a} {B : A → Set b} → (x : A) → ((y : A) → B y) → B x
$ x = λ f → f x

success-usage : ∀{a b}{A : Set a}{B : Set b} → A → (A → B) → B
success-usage x = $ x

failed-usage : ∀{A : Set} → (∀{B : Set} → B) → (∀{B : Set} → B → A) → A
failed-usage {A} bs = $ (bs {A})
-- works : λ {A} bs f → $ (bs {A}) f
```

Thank-you :-)

Comment: Note that whatever you end up using for sections, you won't be able to use it with operators where the second argument's type depends on the first value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The development version of Agda (2.4.3) has sections:

```
open import Function

ok₁ : ∀{a b}{A : Set a}{B : Set b} → A → (A → B) → B
ok₁ x = _$ x

ok₂ : ∀{A : Set} → (∀{B : Set} → B) → (∀{B : Set} → B → A) → A
ok₂ {A} bs = _$ (bs {A})

ok₃ : ∀{a b}{A : Set a}{B : Set b} → (A → B) → A → B
ok₃ f = f $_
```

Comment: That's awesome! But I'm not very techy-savvy, or in immediate need of the feature, so I think I'll have to wait for the released version.